# Maps between direct limits and functoriality of $f^{-1}:Shv(Y) \rightarrow Shv(X)$ and $f_{*}:Shv(X) \rightarrow Shv(Y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory

My question rises from exercise 1.18 in chapter 2 of Hartshorne. Given a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, one has to show there is a natural bijection between $\mathrm{Hom}_X(f^{-1}\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_Y(\mathcal{G},f_*\mathcal{F})$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf over $Y$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf over $X$.

So far I have shown that we have natural maps $f^{-1}f_* \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ and $G \rightarrow f_* f^{-1} G$. I am not completely sure what is meant about naturality. My guess is that given a diagram $\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
f^{-1}\mathcal{G}_1 @>{}>> \mathcal{F}_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
f^{-1}\mathcal{G}_2 @>{}>> \mathcal{F}_2
\end{CD}

one should get a diagram

\begin{CD}
\mathcal{G}_1 @>{}>> f_*\mathcal{F}_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathcal{G}_2 @>{}>> f_*\mathcal{F}_2
\end{CD}

and analogously interchanging the roles of $f^{-1}$ and $f_*$. A first question is "am I right?". If so, now applying $f_*$ to the first diagram and using the natural maps mentioned above, I would have a diagram

\begin{CD}
\mathcal{G}_1 @>{}>> f_* f^{-1} \mathcal{G}_1 @>>> \ f_*\mathcal{F}_1\\
& @VVV @VVV \\
\mathcal{G}_2 @>{}>> f_* f^{-1} \mathcal{G}_2 @>>> f_*\mathcal{F}_2
\end{CD}

and I would have to build the first arrow. By simplicity, instead of the sheaves given by $f^{-1}$, I argue using the presheaves whose associated sheaf is the inverse image. Then given $U$ open in $Y$, I want a map $\mathcal{G}_1 (U) \rightarrow \mathcal{G}_2(U)$, given one between
\begin{equation}
\lim_{f(f^{-1}(U)) \subset V} \mathcal{G}_1(V) \rightarrow \lim_{f(f^{-1}(U)) \subset V} \mathcal{G}_2(V)
\end{equation}

Now, in general a map between direct limits does not come from a map between the direct systems, right? Hence I was wondering how to build the map I want. In know that $U$ is in the set where I do the direct limit, and then my guess was:

given a section in $\mathcal{G}_1(U)$, I send it to its class $\overline{s}$ in the direct limit. Then, for this precise section (not for the whole homomorphism), the map between the direct limits is given by assigning a section $t \in \mathcal{G}_2(V)$, with $f(f^{-1}(U))\subset V \subset U$.

Now my idea was: I cannot ask for $V$ to be $U$, but if I manage to do something like this around each point $P \in U$ (i.e. I take $s_{|U_P}$ with $P \in U_P \subset U$ with the property that if I do the procedure described for $U$, I find a $V_P$ with $P \in V_P$), then I can glue the sections each point give me, since they come from the map of direct limits restricted to smaller sets.

Now I have two doubts: I know that the sections I pick for points $P$ and $Q$ agree eventually in come intersection,  since both have to describe the image of $\overline{s}_{|V_p \cap V_Q}$, but I don't know anything about $V_P \cap V_Q$. Also, I am not sure that for any point $P$ I can pick the $V_P$ I want.

Are my ideas in teh right direction or am I completely lost? Also, am I in trouble defining the images I want since I am not usinge the sheaves $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}_i$ but the presheaves defining them?

Comment: "Natural" here is meant in the sense of category theory. You should look up adjoint functors.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Iversen's "Cohomology of Sheaves" [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/iversensheaves.pdf), from page 96, and especially page 98, where it is shown that the direct image functor is left adjoint to the inverse image functor, which is exactly what you want.